# Number Patterns

Tags: number-sequence

Your mission, if you choose to accept it, is three parts: A) Figure out the pattern; B) Give an eleven-number sequence beginning with 2 that follows the same pattern; and C) Give an eleven-*letter* sequence beginning with α (alpha).

```
A)  1, 3, 34, 5, 56, 10, 160, 4, 42, 8, 118
B)  2, ?,  ?, ?,  ?,  ?,   ?, ?,  ?, ?,   ?
C)  α, ?,  ?, ?,  ?,  ?,   ?, ?,  ?, ?,   ?
```

Hint:

> For part C, you may need multiple letters in a given spot in the sequence.

Hint 2:

> Each number in the sequence is not necessarily directly related to the previous number.

Hint 3:

> Think about aspects of each number individually as opposed to aspects of how they fit into the sequence as a whole.

Comment: Would you like to tell us whether these are length-11 sequences or length-11 initial segments of longer (perhaps infinite) sequences? That is, would it have made sense to ask us to *continue* the first sequence?

Comment: Yes. It is absolutely possible to continue these sequences ad infinitum. Depending on the starting number, it's theoretically possible to continue the sequence backwards, as well, though with 1 and 2 it is impossible (hint hint).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence A is obtained in the following way:

> 1. Start with a number (1 in the example).  The sequence is now **1**.
>  2. Add to the sequence the number of letters of the number (1=one, so add 3).  The sequence is now **1,3**.
>  3. Add the sum of the numerical values of the letters of the same number (o=15, n=14, e=5, so add 34).  The sequence is now **1, 3, 34**.
>  4. Apply 2. and 3. again to the first number in the sequence to which they have not yet been applied.  Repeat.

Thus the sequence B is

> 2, 3, 58, 5, 56, 10, 115, 4, 42, 8, 118.

As for C,

> I can think of several ways to do it, but I'll try this one (keeping in mind that the Greek alphabet has 24 letters): in step 2., use the number of letters in the English way to write the Greek letter ("alpha" has 5 letters), and convert again to Greek letters (if α is the digit 0, then ζ is 5).  Of course, we count in base 24 here!
>  In step 3., same thing, again in base 24 converted to Greek letters.

This gives

> α, ζ, βν, ε, γε, η, γπ, θ, δτ, ν, ζη.

Comment: Absolutely correct! Well done. :)

Answer (score 1):

<sup>(Community evidence locker— feel free to add or correct)</sup>

Too good-looking to resist sharing, whether pertinent or not,
the factors of sequence A are quite reminiscent of a binomial distribution,
with a lot of balanced 7-liness.

```
                               2
                               4
                               5
                               8
                      2       10       2
                      4       16       3
                      7       20       6
                      8       32       7
               2     14   2   40      14   2    2
              17     28   5   80   2  21   4   59

    A)  1, 3, 34, 5, 56, 10, 160,  4, 42,  8, 118


    i   1  2   3  4   5   6    7   8   9  10   11
```

Comment: ... I have absolutely no idea what I'm looking at here. :/

Comment: The columns show the factors of each element in sequence A. I'll try to make that clearer.

Comment: Got it. Yeah, that has absolutely nothing to do with anything. But +1 for an interesting lead.

Comment: Oky doke, I'll leave it alone for now and let these comments serve as a guardrail for solvers. Very intriguing puzzle.